# How to know the object type from a json with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I have a Node JS Express API which has a flexible endpoint. That endpoint will receive a JSON from the request body and it should know the matching object it belongs.

**Eg 1:**

```
POST /api
{
   "id": 1,
   "username": "felipe"
}
```

The json above should be an `User` object.

**Eg 2:**

```
POST /api
{
   "price": 15.5,
   "description": "Product description"
}
```

The json above should be a `Product` object.

How can I dynamically know the object type that I'm receiving from the request? Is there any type os schema or another concept I could use?

Comment: You'd have to explicitly encode the desired object type in your JSON body. JSON has no "type" feature intrinsically.

Comment: The only way to do this I can think of is to base it on the keys received. If key `description` is present, it's a Product, if `username` is present, it's a User...

Comment: Better try using typescript and manage interfaces for your json Objects (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)[https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html]

Comment: you can try `try {JSON.parse(yourResponse)}catch(e){} `. and if it parses, determine if the attributes match. I think this is a workaround from IMHO. But it solves your problem, I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of control hover the data sent in the Json (something like a Mongo document for example) then may be you can just add a "type" row on your object before sending it in order to let your Node server retrieve this data and handle it how you want.
An other solution would be to have different routing like `/api/user` and `/api/products` then you dont need to change your data sent, but you will probably have lots of duplication.

Otherwise there is no way you can know an object type inside the json.

Comment: Hello @Minirock, the problem is that the project must have only one route and the json object will never have a "type" attribute. I guess I should think on a way of discover the object type by its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

the "best" way to do it is by following the 12 factor proposal blah blah https://12factor.net/ but to fulfill your goal we have a couple of options we can use them query params

`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/end-point?kind=user` or

`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/end-point?kind=otherOption`

```js
import express from 'express';
import {json, urlencoded} from 'body-parser';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import compress from 'compression';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express()

app.use(helmet());
app.use(compress());
app.use(json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api/v1/myAwesomeEndPoint', (req, res) => {
  const {kind} = req.query.params;

  if (kind === 'user') {
    // do them user logic
    return res.status(200).send({success: true, message: '<3'})
  }

  // apply the other option logic
  return res.status(200).send({success: true, message: '<3'})
})
```

but if you really want to have the same uri we still can do it like so

```js
import express from 'express';
import {json, urlencoded} from 'body-parser';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import compress from 'compression';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express()

app.use(helmet());
app.use(compress());
app.use(json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api/v1/myAwesomeEndPoint', (req, res) => {
 const {body} = req;

  if (body.hasOwnProperty('user')) {
    // do them user logic
    return res.status(200).send({success: true, message: '<3'})
  }


  return res.status(200).send({success: true, message: '<3'})
})
```